# jQuery get dynamic nested element to call animate method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically adding data to a div by pressing a button called view.

That is working fine, however I decided to take it a step further and another nested dynamic element.

I can make the call just fine from the dynamic div. The issue I am running into now is when I call the dynamic div to expand the all-views it only expands one; it will not expand any others.

I have verified that my call is correct by adding a `var d = Date()` and calling the milliseconds as a data-value.

I did some searching and found the `parents()` and `find()` methods. I can find the div but it still calls only one.

I have dynamically added 100 divs and it still only calls the newest one. I have also tried another on() with the resize and other triggered events.

What am I missing here?

```js
$("#view").click(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  $("#dynamic-div-post").prepend('<div class="dynamic-div" style="width: 100%; background-color: red"><div class="col-6"><button id="btn-view" type="button" data-value="test-view" class="btn btn-outline-dark w-100 border-0 d-none d-sm-block"><img class="" src="/img/like.png" style="height: 18px;">view</button></div></div><div class="row dynamic-div" style="width: 100%; background-color: blue;"><div class="col-6 p-0"><div class="all-views" style="background-color: blue; width: 100%; display: none"></div></div></div>');
});

$("#dynamic-div-post").on('click', "#btn-view", function() {
  //alert($(this).parents('#dynamic-div-post').find('.all-views').css('display'));
  switch ($(this).parents('#dynamic-div-post').find('.all-views').css('display')) {
    case 'none':
      $(this).parents('#dynamic-div-post').find('.all-views').css({
        'border-top': "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
        'display': 'block'
      }).animate({
        "min-height": "150px"
      }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
      break;
    case 'block':
      $(this).parents('#dynamic-div-post').find('.all-views').animate({
        borderWidth: 0,
        "min-height": "0",
        display: "none"
      }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).parents('#dynamic-div-post').find('.all-views').css({
          'border-top': "none",
          'display': 'none'
        })
      });
      break;
  }
  //$(this).blur();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dynamic-div-post' class='static-div'>
</div>
<div id='div-view' class='static-div'>
  <button id='view'>view</button>
</div>
```

Comment: first you have a mistake here `<scirpt>` should be `<script>`

Comment: If you add the dynamic content more than once, then you have the problem because `id` should be unique. So if `<div id="all-views"` is added more than once you code will only work for the first element. Use `classes`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - sorry I had to re-type that line because I accidently cleared it. I didn't proof read the re-write.

Comment: Please click edit, then scroll down to edit above snippet. Click it and create a [mcve] from the snippet I made you

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - thank you for the reply. how does it know then on the other dynamic run? `code` $("#dynamic-div-post").on('click', "#btn-view", function(){
  alert($(this).data("value"));
  $(this).blur();
 });

Comment: You have duplicate IDs - change id="btn-view" to class=".btn-view" (add it to the other button classes) and use `$("#dynamic-div-post").on('click', ".btn-view", function() {`

Comment: @mplungjan  changing to classes still produces the same thing --->  You have duplicate IDs - change id="btn-view" to class=".btn-view" (add it to the other button classes) and use $("#dynamic-div-post").on('click', ".btn-view", function() {

Comment: There may be more issues, but "_it still only calls the newest one_" is certainly the use of ID

Comment: @mplungjan - I did change it to classes and it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: I see your code now. I will try to test what is wrong

Comment: So I found the other issue and retracted the vote. You DID have several issues with ID vs CLASS but the last issue was that the button was not in the same container as the text you wanted to show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The button parent div was not a parent of the allViews

1. Change all dynamic elements from having ID to a class
2. Give the parent container a class we can recognise. Too many dynamic-div classes
3. You needed the NEXT div to open and close.
4. I simplified the animation

```js
$("#view").click(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  $("#dynamic-div-post").prepend('<div class="dynamic-div container" style="width: 100%; background-color: red"><div class="col-6"><button  type="button" data-value="test-view" class="btn-view btn btn-outline-dark w-100 border-0 d-none d-sm-block"><img class="" src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/facebook-like.png" style="height: 18px;">view</button></div></div><div class="row dynamic-div" style="width: 100%; background-color: blue;"><div class="col-6 p-0"><div class="all-views" style="background-color: yellow; width: 100%;">Here is some text</div></div></div>');
});

$("#dynamic-div-post").on('click', ".btn-view", function() {
  const $allViews = $(this).closest('.container').next().find('.all-views');
  if (!$allViews.is(".open")) {
    $allViews.css({
      'border-top': "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
      'display': 'block'
    }).animate({
      "min-height": "150px"
    }, 1000, function() {
      $allViews.addClass("open")
    });
  } else {
    $allViews.animate({
      "borderWidth": 0,
      "min-height": 0,
      "display": "none"
    },function() { $allViews.removeClass("open") });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dynamic-div-post' class='static-div'>
</div>
<div id='div-view' class='static-div'>
  <button id='view'>view</button>
</div>
```

Comment: no, it is not working on my side. just show the view button

Comment: also, I have updated the reference above to classes. and it works on here differently. it opens all divs and closses all divs

Comment: I am looking at your code. I have tried all of that. the best I have found is .children().children(). for some reason it was only getting on child with the .children() and when you call it twice you get three

Comment: I am thinking that I will need to make a static function like `function divExp(selectedDiv){methods here}` and then call that method from the other script and pass the data

Comment: Please see update. The last issue was that the button was not in the same parent div as the content.

Comment: I see... let me try it on my end.

Comment: Ok. I was able to see what you did and how it was instantiated. thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: So you see. Not rude. Just terse and needing to see enough code to be able to fix it

Comment: Yes, I can see that you're to the point. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @CalRob2005 I simplified the animation and test for open, The div IS visible when partly closed

Comment: thank you. Do you recommend any ebooks on jQuery that I can read further to advance my knowledge? I learned PHP last year and got 6 college credits for it. I took 2 100 level classes in school for extra credit. I am doing jQuery and trying to apply the PHP knowledge I gained to get more extra credit so I can get into Stanford.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not read e-books on JavaScript programming since I taught myself JS in 1995 from the book "JavaScript, the Definitive Guide" - the best is to study examples at jquery.com and highly voted answers here at SO.
Another cool thing to do is to study Vanilla JS first. For example many things can be done with addEventListener and document.querySelector / querySelectorAll. When you can do those, you can understand jQuery better. I am personally using jQuery less and less after having used it a LOT until a year or so ago

Comment: Cool! That's a big help. I am new to this like I said so I am trying to absorbe as much information as I can. I really, really appreciate it! I hope you have a wonderful day, afternoon, or evening where ever you're at! I am off to bed. it's 2:14am over here

Comment: It's 11:15am here in The Hague. You too. Get some sleep ! ;)

Comment: People keep marking down my questions and I have been banned from asking further questions so I was removing all my posted questions seeing that everyone thinks I am dumb and shouldn't be asking questions.